# How to change ComboBox keyboard input behaviour

Tags: winforms, combobox, keyboard

(WinForms Project in Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4, C#)

I have a ComboBox in DropDownList style with a fixed set of items which are the integral numbers from 1 to 40, i. e., the ComboBox is used to input a number from 1 to 40.

Now when users use the keyboard to enter a new value, say "1", and the current value of the control is "2", the ComboBox first jumps to "10", whereas I would prefer it to jump to "1" and only on the second keypress jump to the second entry beginning with "1", which would be "10".

Is there a simple way to change this behaviour?

Comment: ComboBox does an incremental search, starting at the currently selected item. Typing 1 0 will lead you to the entry starting with "10", no matter which one was selected. What you desire would disable the incremental search feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a "simple way". You need build a custom ComboBox class and override [the Control.ProcessKeyEventArgs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processkeyeventargs.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

`ComboBox` does an incremental search, starting at the currently selected item. Typing 1 0 will lead you to the entry starting with "10", no matter which one was selected.

How about padding all entries with leading zeros, so the user would type "01" for the first entry?

That also would make sure that the entries are sorted correctly (should you ever sort the list items, and should they contain text behind the numerical characters, as probably is the case sooner or later ;) ).

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of setting the selectedIndex to 0 in the KeyDown handler to make the search start from the beginning, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Set it to -1, or set SelectedValue to Nothing. Problem in resetting it in KeyDown destroys the incremental search feature since you always force the search to start at the first item (and setting the item stops incremental search anyways, I believe).